ISPF Panel Verify of a USS PATH
Has anyone developed a technique to validate a USS Path using the ISPF Panel VER statement?
I know I could do it using PANEL REXX but would prefer to use a VER statement.
Thank you

Not sure what you're looking for here.  Isn't any string up to 1023 characters a potentially valid path?  Do the VER DSNAME* options do anything other than validate that qualifiers are 8 bytes or less and combined do not exceed 44 characters excluding the member name if it is supplied?

the VER DSNAME does more than verify each qualifier is 8 characters or less, it also validates those characters as some chars are not valid in a qualifier and some are not valid to start a qualifier.
